# Problem saving custom attribute in rails devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, strong-parameters

The authentication system in my app is handled by devise and now I want each user in my system to belong to an organisation. So each organisation will have multiple users. 
When signing up, each user will select which organisation they want to join.

When a user is signing up, and they select and organisation from a combo-box, they get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Organisation(#70213198483780) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#70213152374240)
```

**The following is what my source code looks like:**

app/models/organisation.rb

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :activities
  belongs_to :organisation
end
```

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organisation %><br />
    <%= f.select :organisation, Organisation.all.collect { |o| [ o.organisation_name, o.id ] }%>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:organisation])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should change in your form to

`<%= f.select :organisation_id, Organisation.all.collect { |o| [ o.organisation_name, o.id ] }%>`

Because the dropdown makes `organisation.name` as key and `organisation.id` as value.

Then change `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:organisation_id])`  to allow `organisation_id` to be assigned to user

Instead of using `collect` on `Organisation.all`, use `Organisation.all.pluck(:name, :id)`. It will give same result as but a more optimised query.

Comment: After making those changes, I'm getting the following error:                                                           

    undefined method `organisation_id' for #<User:0x00007ff91ff252e0>
    Did you mean?  organisation
                   organisation=
                   organisation?
                   organisation_was


And,

Comment: Don't you have `organisation_id` in `User` model ?